# Moving css only menu items 1 by 1 when resizing window

Tags: html, css

I have the below shown css only menu, but am wondering how I can, when the browser window gets smaller and the menu items doesnt fit, how I can move them one by one! onto the last, right most item "more..." so they create a sub  menu there instead. Please see the following pictures of how first item "seventh" and "eighth" are moved onto "more..." and the second picture shows what should happen when you hover over "seventh", it should reveal its original sub menu items.

My current code: (pen with same for easier resizing: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oZoMbK)

```css
* {box-sizing:border-box;}
.nav{
 background-color:#d6336c;
  font-size:20px;
}
.nav ul{
    list-style: none;
}
.nav ul li{
 padding:2px 20px;
 float: left;
 position:relative;
 background: #1bc2a2;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
.nav ul li ul {
 display:none;
  position: absolute;
 background-color:orange;
  left: 0;
}
.nav ul li ul, .nav li li {
    min-width: 100%;
}
.nav ul li:hover > ul{
 display: block;
}
.nav ul ul ul{
 left:100%;
 top:0;
}

.nav a{
 color:#ffffff;
}
ul,li{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
```

```html
 <div class="nav">
<ul>
 <li><a href="#">first</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">second</a>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">sub1 first</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">sub1 second</a> 
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">sub2 first</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">sub2 second</a>
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">sub3 first</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub3 second</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">sub3 third</a></li>
   </ul>
   </li>
  </ul>
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">sub2 third</a></li>
 </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">third</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">.</a>
   <li><a href="#">.</a>
   <li><a href="#">.</a>
  </ul>
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">fourth</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">fifth</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">sixth</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">seventh</a>
 <ul>
  <li><a href="#">cats</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">dogs</a>
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#">beagle</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">boxer</a></li>
  </ul>        
  </li>
  <li><a href="#">birds</a></li>
 </ul>    
 </li>
 <li><a href="#">eighth</a></li>
 <li><a href="#">more...</a></li>
</ul>
</div>
```

First image when hovering "more...":
[image]

Second image, when hovering "seventh" under "more...": 
[image]

I cant figure out how its done, only with media queries but I dont want set specific values as the menu items width might change/be dynamic. The following two pens somehow moves the items one by one as they dont fit when resizing the screen:

https://codepen.io/VPenkov/pen/wMZBOg & https://codepen.io/tejasukmana/pen/bZKNrJ

I really want to keep this css only, no javascript.

thanks in advance for any help!

Frank

Comment: This jquery plugin does what you need it to do, maybe have a look how it's built https://github.com/VPenkov/okayNav

Comment: @DragosMicu thank you, I will take a look but I really want to keep this css only. Thanks for showing it though, Did not realize one of the codepen examples used this plugin.